# Scala - Instantiate generic type with arguments?

Tags: scala, generics

From what I understand if class A and B did not have any arguments then `ClassTag` could be used here but since they do have arguments, not sure how I could avoid creating 2 methods here, one for SimpleA and another for SimpleB with the same body..

```
trait Simple {
  val id: UUID
  val name: String
}
case class SimpleA(id: UUID, name: String) extends Simple
case class SimpleB(id: UUID, name: String) extends Simple

def fromTupleToSimple[T <: Simple](sf: (UUID, String)): T = new T(sf._1, sf._2)
```

Trying to instantiate T gives the error `class type required but T found`. Not sure how these types of problems are normally solved.

Comment: I think ```def fromTupleToSimple(sf: (UUID, String)): Simple``` should be enough

Comment: Just curious, what is the use case for that? I mean, if there is no other parameter (to choose which class to instantiate), why would you have 2 classes?

Comment: @insan-e Well, some methods can only receive SimpleA and others SimpleB's, they represent diff entities.

Comment: @SamD In this case, I really need the more specific type since it's going to be validated later on through some macros in sangria graphql. Also can't do new Simple() because it's a trait.

Comment: `(SimpleA.apply _).tupled`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can still you `ClassTag`, it just becomes a bit trickier:

```
def fromTupleToSimple[T <: Simple : ClassTag](sf: (UUID, String)) = classTag
  .runtimeClass
  .getConstructors
  .head
  .newInstance(sf._1, sf._2)
  .asInstanceOf[T]
```

Comment: The drawback of this implementation is that it evaluates the type in runtime

Comment: That's the whole point of having a type parameter ;) 
If you knew the type at compile type, you would not need it.